# Returning a single array to a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

Full disclosure; I needed to know this for an assignment. I wanted to return a single array to a multidimensional array from a method. I circumvented the issue with the below code by returning it to another 1-dimensional array then using a for loop to transfer values.

```
public class test 
{
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        int[][] array1 = new int [100][5];
        int[] temp = new int [5];
        int num = 0;

        temp = setValue();

        for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++) // cycle 1
        {
            array1[num][i]= temp[i];
        }

        System.out.format("\n\n");

    }

    public static int[] setValue()
    {
        int[] array3 = new int [5];

        for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            array3[i]= 2;
        }

        return array3;
    }
}
```

Is there a more conventional way to return array3 to array1 without cycle 1? Something along the lines of

```
array1[num][] = setValue();
```

Comment: You can replace the for-loop for the second dimension (`[5]`) by a call to `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange` but one loop for the first dimension is necessary (but not contained in your code).

Comment: One remark yet: A multidimensional Java array isn't like such an array in C/C++ (where it is just a 1-dim array with different indexing). It is a 1-dim array of references to arrays of the second dim.

Comment: `array1[num] = setValue()`?

Answer (score 3):

Comments:

- The method returns a new array, so no need to initialize `temp`, or better yet, initialize it to return value:

  ```
  int[] temp = setValue();
  ```
- Java doesn't have 2D arrays, just arrays of arrays, so the entire inner array can be replaced, instead of copying values:

  <strike>`for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) // cycle 1`</strike>
  <strike>`{`</strike>
  `array1[num] = temp;`
  <strike>`}`</strike>
- When you do that, you shouldn't allocate the inner arrays, i.e. replace `[5]` with `[]`:

  ```
  int[][] array1 = new int[100][];
  ```
- Now there is actually no need for `temp` anymore, leaving `main` as just:

  ```
  int[][] array1 = new int[100][];
  int num = 0;

  array1[num] = setValue();
  ```
- Since you probably want to fill the entire 2D array:

  ```
  int[][] array1 = new int[100][];

  for (int num = 0; num < array1.length; num++) {
      array1[num] = setValue();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

As @VinceEmigh hinted above you can simply do `array1[num] = setValue();`

see

```
int arr[][] = new int[5][];

for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    arr[x] = setValue();
}
for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
        System.out.println(arr[x][y]);
    }
}
```